# How to change block-comment shortcut in Visual Studio 2019 (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to comment multiple lines of C# code in Visual Studio.
The default shortcut "Comment Code Block Ctrl+K+C/Ctrl+K+U" works, but I am used to Ctrl+Shift+K.
I am trying to change it following most guides:

> On the menu bar, choose Tools > Options.

> Expand Environment, and then choose Keyboard.

> Optional: Filter the list of commands by entering all or part of the name of the command, without spaces, in the Show commands containing box.

> In the list, choose the command to which you want to assign a keyboard shortcut.

I tried multiple like "Toggle block comment", but nothing happens when I try the key combination.
[image]

Does anyone have an Idea how to configure it properly?

Comment: I'm not following what you mean - all you should have to do is perform the desired shortcut combination you wish in the "Press shortcut keys" textbox.  The default for block comments is `Ctrl + Shift + /` as denoted in the drop down.

Comment: When assigning a shortcut, please make sure to select "Text Editor" in the "Use new shortcut in" dropdown.

Comment: @TimothyG. the default "official documentation" is "Ctrl+K+C" and it is working, in the options I see "Ctrl + Shift + /" which is not working and even if I change it, it still does not work.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I tried, but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Previously, to toggle block comments I go to...

> edit>advanced>toggle block comment

But it didn't have any shortcuts assigned.

Now I followed the setting from the above-displayed image and I set the shortcut...

> ctrl+shift+/

It works for me on Visual Studio 2019.